# How do I decrypt an error report?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I published the application in Google Play and I received such a user report about the error. What is this error? And how is it to decipher?

signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR), fault addr 60e743dc

```
r0 5b79c2c8  r1 0000001f  r2 fffffe9c  r3 00000000
r4 849fc9d6  r5 415bcd68  r6 5fd0787b  r7 41c7bd00
r8 60e743d8  r9 5b79c2c8  sl 5fd07840  fp befeff94
ip 415b5ed4  sp befefd88  lr 4155c065  pc 415761c8  cpsr 60010030
d0  000002f8443e070a  d1  00000000443e070a
d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
d6  0000000000000000  d7  443e070a00000000
d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
d16 ffffffffffffffff  d17 00000000983a9adc
d18 0000000095dba510  d19 0000000000000000
d20 000000000000000a  d21 3ff0000000000000
d22 0000000000000000  d23 4004000000000000
d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 4004000000000000
d28 3ff0000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 4000000000000000
scr 60000010
```

backtrace:

```
#00  pc 0008b1c8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dexFindClass(DexFile const*, char const*)+33)
#01  pc 00071061  /system/lib/libdvm.so
#02  pc 0006ae75  /system/lib/libdvm.so
#03  pc 00000214  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
```

code around pc:

```
415761a8 468a4ff7 36fff101 f8d04681 24018024  
415761b8 e001211f 3404fb01 3f01f816 d1f92b00  
415761c8 7004f8d8 0c0cf04f ea043f01 fb0c0507  
415761d8 68f08605 68b2b198 d10d42a2 b02cf8d9  
415761e8 44584651 c004f8cd ecf6f797 c004f8dd  
415761f8 6930b910 e0024458 403d3501 e8bde7e7  
41576208 b5108ffe 20004604 46024601 ecfcf797  
41576218 f1046a22 3a0c010c 4010e8bd b96cf005  
41576228 e92d296f 460441ff 4617460e 4951d807  
41576238 20064a51 447a4479 ebf0f797 2034e095  
41576248 ebcef797 28004605 808ff000 22342100  
41576258 ebdef797 46204949 22044479 ecdaf797  
41576268 d12f2800 1d204946 22044479 ecd2f797  
41576278 7960b170 90007923 200679a1 79e29101  
41576288 92024940 44794a40 f797447a e069ebc8  
41576298 4620602c 462a4631 f93af000 d0612800
```

code around lr:

```
4155c044 f01a9907 4607f8ae f8d5b160 f1b880a4  
4155c054 d0070f00 f8d8e00f 99070000 f8a1f01a  
4155c064 b9404607 4394f8d5 6474b10c 9807e2a4  
4155c074 f830f7d9 69b9e277 0000f8d8 6ac2b109  
4155c084 910c1851 a80cb181 fa56f7d8 a80c9014  
4155c094 fa52f7d8 a80c9015 fa4ef7d8 a80c9016  
4155c0a4 fa4af7d8 e0039017 2210a814 ecb2f7b1  
4155c0b4 f8d8990c 910d4000 68394620 f7eb940a  
4155c0c4 687afeaf 46814ba0 0103ea02 9200b151  
4155c0d4 4aa649a5 44792005 464b447a eca0f7b1  
4155c0e4 e1772400 b93c9c08 447949a1 ed76f7b1  
4155c0f4 f8d5b910 e00840c4 20189a14 f002fb00  
4155c104 30a02102 ea72f7be 2c004604 8162f000  
4155c114 f8d52100 462020c4 f9d3f7dd f7fe4620  
4155c124 6a21fdeb 9a08687b 0003ea41 214c6220  
4155c134 f8c44620 f7dd9018 68b9f9c4 f04f68f8
```

Comment: You won't be able to do that. This kind of error is something that happened deep in the native code of Android SDK. And unless you obtain some data on reproducing the issue, this error report is useless.